# PTIJ: why can’t Jews be dare-y with meat

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Halacha is that Jews separate meat from being dare-y. Is there a reason for this, especially given the principle of shomer petaim hashem (see psalms 116:6).

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there is shomer petaim hashem. However if a person is darey for meat, that shows that meat is very important. The gemara pesachim 49a says an am haaretz is forbidden to eat meat.
If a person is darey for meat, an ignoramous would be more tempted to eat meat.
Therefore one can't be darey for meat, lest the ignoramous be tempted to eat it.